# Serial communication and CRLF C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

i Have question about CRLF after sending a string to the serial port.
Let me explain what im trying to do, Under here there is an example.

```
[ACR]  CRLF
10:90  CRLF
11:20  CRLF
12:2.1 CRLF
```

That is what im trying to do but i cant get anywhere, Can someone help me with this.
i think i have to do the CRLF to start a newline but if you have other suggestions they will be more then welcome
This is what i've done:

**Code:**

```
private void SendMessageTest()
        {
            var content = _durCleaningTextbox.Text;

            byte[] array = ComPort.StringToBytes(content);




                _comport.WriteBytes(array);
                _comport.ReadBytes(array, array.Length, 1000);
                string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array);
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
```

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Communication
{
    public class ComPort
    {
        private readonly SerialPort _serialPort;

        public ComPort(string portName, int baudRate)
        {
            _serialPort = new SerialPort();

            _serialPort.PortName = portName;
            _serialPort.BaudRate = baudRate;

            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;

            _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;


            // _serialPort.WriteBufferSize = 1;
            _serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = true;

            _serialPort.Open();

            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 20000;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 20000;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            while (ReadByte() != -1)
                continue;
        }

        private byte[] _array = new byte[] {0};

        public void WriteByte(byte value)
        {
            _array[0] = value;
            _serialPort.Write(_array, 0, 1);
            // _serialPort.BaseStream.WriteByte(value);
            _serialPort.BaseStream.Flush();
        }

        public void WriteBytes(byte[] array)
        {
            _serialPort.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
        }

        public void WriteBytes(byte[] array, int index, int length )
        {
            _serialPort.Write(array, index, length);
        }

        private int _readTimeOut = -1;

        public int ReadByte(int timeOut = 200)
        {
            if (timeOut != _readTimeOut)
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = _readTimeOut = timeOut;
            try
            {
                //return _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadByte();
                return _serialPort.ReadByte();
                // _serialPort.Read(array, 0, 1);
                // return array[0];
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        public int ReadBytes(byte[] array, int length, int timeOut = 200)
        {
            if (timeOut != _readTimeOut)
                _serialPort.ReadTimeout = _readTimeOut = timeOut;
            try
            {
                //return _serialPort.BaseStream.ReadByte();

                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ( bytesRead < length )
                    bytesRead += _serialPort.Read(array, bytesRead, length - bytesRead);

                // _serialPort.Read(array, 0, 1);
                // return array[0];
                return bytesRead;
            }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// sends string followed by CR - LF
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="line"></param>
        public void WriteLine(String line)
        {
            WriteBytes(StringToBytes(line + "\r\n"));
        }

        public static byte[] StringToBytes(string input)
        {
            return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            try
            {
                _serialPort.DtrEnable = false;
                _serialPort.RtsEnable = false;
                _serialPort.Close();
            }
            catch(IOException)
            {

            }
        }

        public bool Dtr
        {
            get { return _serialPort.DtrEnable; }
            set { _serialPort.DtrEnable = value; }
        }

        public bool Rts
        {
            get { return _serialPort.RtsEnable; }
            set { _serialPort.RtsEnable = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] array = ComPort.StringToBytes(content + "\r\n");
```

Or use your `WriteLine` method which already does this. So:

```
byte[] array = ComPort.StringToBytes(content);
_comport.WriteBytes(array);
```

Becomes:

```
_comport.WriteLine(content);
```

Comment: Thanks this was execly what i was looking for, Thank you very much. I will accept this as anwser asap

Comment: An quick question about this, i have multiple textboxes so how can i put them in var content

Comment: The default Newline used by WriteLine is LF(\n) only.

Comment: @dbasnett Their `WriteLine`, i.e. `ComPort.WriteLine` from question: `WriteBytes(StringToBytes(line + "\r\n"));`

Comment: Koornstra so many ways. I'd write a new method on comport called `WriteLines` that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`. Formats them into a single line with '\r\n' after each line and sends that as one.

Answer (score 0):

You need send the commands CR (Carriage Return) and LF (Line Feed, or new line).

For this is just to send your command plus the the CR and LF like this:

```
string command = "myCommand";

port.write(string.format("{0}\r\n", command));
```

**\r\n = CR + LF -> Used as a new line character in Windows**